# How to access and reuse the smooths in the `mgcv` package in `R`?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, spline, mgcv

I am checking out the `mgcv` package in `R` and I would like to know
how to update a model based on new data. For example, suppose I have the
following data and I am interested in fitting a cubic regression spline.

```r
# Load library.
library(mgcv)

# Set seed.
set.seed(2022)

# Data
x <- seq(10, 100, by = 10)
y <- sort(runif(10))
```

I can fit a model using the `mgcv::s()` function for transforming my predictor variable, where `bs = "cr"` stands for *cubic regression spline* as indicated in the
documentation (i.e., `?mgcv::s`).

```r
# Fit.
model <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr"))

# Print model.
model

# Family: gaussian 
# Link function: identity 
#
# Formula:
# y ~ s(x, bs = "cr")
#
# Estimated degrees of freedom:
# 7.51  total = 8.51 
# 
# GCV score: 0.001123237
```

I assume `mgcv::s()` is used used to
determine the inner knots for the spline basis functions? If I want to
interpolate the entire range of `x`, it seems that I can use the `predict`
function.

```r
# Prepare range of `x` for interpolation.
x_new <- 10:100

# Interpolate.
mgcv_interpolation <- predict(model, type = "link", newdata = data.frame(x = x_new))

# Plot.
plot(x, y, pch = 19)
lines(x_new, mgcv_interpolation, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

What is not clear to me is how to update the model when new data (i.e., `y`)
comes in. For instance, suppose my new data looks something like this.

```r
# Set seed.
set.seed(2022)
y_new <- sort(sample(y, size = length(y), replace = TRUE))
```

My understanding is that I could simply use the previously created basis matrix,
but I am not sure how to do that with `mgcv`. For example, this is how I can do
it manually using a B-Spline basis.

```r
# ...
# Suppose that based on some cross-validation procedure `df = 6` is selected.
df <- 6

# Create B-Spline basis functions.
basis <- splines::bs(x, df = df, degree = 3, intercept = TRUE)

# Estimate spline coefficients.
coefficients <- lm.fit(basis, y)$coef

# Compute fitted values.
fitted <- basis %*% coefficients

# Create extended basis for `x_new`.
basis_x_new <- splines::bs(x_new, df = df, degree = 3, intercept = TRUE)

# Interpolate.
bs_interpolation <- basis_x_new %*% coefficients

# Add to previous plot.
lines(x_new, bs_interpolation, lwd = 2, col = "blue")
```

[image]

```r
# Update model based on `y_new`.
coefficients_y_new <- lm.fit(basis, y_new)$coef

# Add points and lines to the previous plot.
points(x, y_new, pch = 19, col = "orange")
lines(x_new, basis_x_new %*% coefficients_y_new, lwd = 2, col = "orange")
```

[image]

I guess my question is how to find whatever `mgcv::s()` creates and
reuse it in subsequent calls of `mgcv::gam`? Or, is there a more
`mgcv`-idiomatic way of doing this?

---

##### Edit 1.

Poking around more, I discovered that I can extract the basis matrix using `mgcv::predict.gam()` with the argument `type = "lpmatrix"`. However, I am still not able to replicate the exact coefficients provided by `mgcv::gam()`. The differences are not large, but  I wonder where they are coming from. For example:

```r
# Extract the basis matrix from the `gam` object.
basis_gam <- mgcv::predict.gam(model, type = "lpmatrix")

# Fit the model using the basis matrix.
model_basis_gam <- mgcv::gam(y ~ basis_gam - 1)

# Compare the coefficients.
round(data.frame(
    difference = coef(model) - coef(model_basis_gam)
), 4)

#              difference
# (Intercept)      0.0000
# s(x).1           0.0004
# s(x).2          -0.0033
# s(x).3           0.0071
# s(x).4          -0.0020
# s(x).5          -0.0016
# s(x).6          -0.0054
# s(x).7           0.0103
# s(x).8          -0.0064
# s(x).9           0.0017
```

---

##### Edit 2.

It seems that that there is a function `mgcv::bam.update()` to update a GAM model for new date, but for models fit via `mgcv::bam()`, and not `mgcv::gam()`. Despite this, the `S3` method `update` appears to work with the `mgcv::gam()` object, perhaps because `class(model)` includes `"gam" "glm" "lm"`, however, there is no mention of this in the documentation. For example:

```r
# Update the model for `y_new`.
model_y_new_via_update <- update(model, data = data.frame(y = y_new))

# Extract the basis matrices for `model` and `model_y_new_via_update`.
basis_model <- mgcv::predict.gam(model, type = "lpmatrix")
basis_model_y_new_via_update <- mgcv::predict.gam(model_y_new_via_update, type = "lpmatrix")

# Check that both models used the same basis matrix.
all(basis_model == basis_model_y_new_via_update)

# TRUE
```

Also, there are still some differences in the coefficients I cannot explain.

```r
# Fit the model using the extracted basis matrix.
model_y_new_via_basis <- mgcv::gam(y_new ~ basis_model - 1)

# Eyeballing the coefficients.
round(data.frame(
    via_update = coef(model_y_new_via_update),
    via_basis = coef(model_y_new_via_basis),
    difference = coef(model_y_new_via_update) - coef(model_y_new_via_basis),
    row.names = names(coef(model))
), 4)

#             via_update via_basis difference
# (Intercept)     0.4420    0.4420     0.0000
# s(x).1         -0.2385   -0.2333    -0.0052
# s(x).2         -0.1901   -0.1689    -0.0212
# s(x).3         -0.0854   -0.1689     0.0835
# s(x).4          0.1315    0.1902    -0.0586
# s(x).5          0.2666    0.2821    -0.0155
# s(x).6          0.2907    0.2821     0.0085
# s(x).7          0.2855    0.2821     0.0033
# s(x).8          0.3119    0.2936     0.0183
# s(x).9          0.3917    0.4036    -0.0120
```

Comment: I believe `smooth.construct2(s(x,bs="cr"), data=list("x"=x), knots=list(10))` will return the set of splines, etc, Perhaps even easier: `smoothCon(s(x,bs="cr"),data=data.frame(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief example

1. Create your `smoothCon` object, using `x`

```
sm = smoothCon(s(x, bs="cr"), data=data.frame(x))[[1]]
```

2. Create simple function to get the beta coefficients given `y` and your `smoothCon` object

```
get_beta <- function(y,sm) {
  as.numeric(coef(lm(y~sm$X-1)))
}
```

3. Create simple function to get the predictions, given `x`, `y`, and and `smoothCon` object

```
get_pred <- function(x,y,sm) {
  PredictMat(sm, data.frame(x=x)) %*% get_beta(y, sm)
}
```

4. Plot the original x,y points in red and the new x,y points in blue

```
plot(x,y, col="red")
points(x,y_new, col="blue")
```

5. Add the lines, using only the new x range (`x_new`), the old (`y`) and new (`y_new`) y values, and the `smoothCon` object

```
lines(x_new, get_pred(x_new,y, sm), col="red")
lines(x_new, get_pred(x_new,y_new, sm), col="blue")
```

[image: smoothCon_example]

Comment: This this helps a lot! However, I think that in this way `mgcv` is not able to select the inner knots for the smooth based on GCV. For example, for the data above, `mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr"))` will yield `Estimated degrees of freedom (DF): 7.51` with `GCV score: 0.001123237`. With `basis <- smoothCon(s(x, bs = "cr"), data = data.frame(x = x))[[1]]$X` followed by `mgcv::gam(y ~ basis - 1)` I see instead 10 DF and a GCV score of zero. And, the coefficients are indeed different. I would like to reuse the basis originally created by `mgcv` based on GCV.

Comment: I added a bit more information to my question above based on some things I tried. Hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: just curious, why not just `gam(new_y~s(x,bs="cr"))`? The basis is the same; its independent of y, and computationally cheap, relative to the actual model fit.

Comment: You are so right! I was under the wrong impression that `mgcv::gam()` determines the best `k` (i.e., basis dimension or the number of knots in for `s()`) based on GCV. It turns out that **this is not true**. Instead, what the GCV is doing is choosing the smooth level of each basis function. Therefore, I think what you are saying is correct---the basis matrix is independent of `y`.

Comment: Yes, the basis is definitely independent of y, so the above is easiest.. However, I still think we should be able to do something like `sm = smoothCon(s(x,bs="cr"),data=data.frame(x=x))`, and somehow utilize that: `gam(y~sm)`, but I haven't been able to figure it out..

Comment: Indeed, what you propose is intuitive and I can imagine that it wouldn't be too complicated for `mgcv::gam()` to check the class of the object returned by `mgcv::smoothCon()` and extract the `[[1]]$X`. But, that's not the way... I will go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks for helping me figure this one out!